# Laplace transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to graph a frequency response of a transfer function H(s). The circuit I have been given is X(t), which is a voltage in, goes threw inductor and then threw parallel placed resistor and capacitor. The Y(t) is across parallel placed capacitor and Resistor. The Impedance of L(inductor) is ZL = sL(where s = alpha + jwt), ZR = R, ZC = 1/sC and Zrc = sRC/R+sC(it is the sum of two impedance in parallel, capacitor and the inductor). I have got the equation for the transfer function H(s), which is below:

```
I(s) = X(s)/ZL+Zrc //which is a total current in a circuit
Y(s) = I(s)*Zrc(voltage across the capacitor and resistor)
H(s) = Y(s)/X(s) => Zrc/Zrc+ZL=> R/(R*C*L*s^2 + L*s + R)
```

Did I get the transfer function H(s) right? Because when I try to graph its frequency response from f = 0:0.001:2 and for s = j2Pf, I don't get the desired output in dB, as I should get negative values instead of positive. 
Finally, what is the impulse response of that system for t = 0:0.001:1, I thought that H(s) is the impulse response. Thank you

Comment: @rayryeng do you have any idea?:)

Answer (score 0):

The current in your circuit is given by

```
I(s) = X(s)/(ZL(s) + Z_RC(s))
```

not

```
X(s)/ZL(s) + Z_RC(s)
```

take care of the parenthesis.

The correct `H(s)` of your system is `R/(R*C*L*s^2 + L*s + R)`
which is a second order system with gain 1, so you will get your expected response on bode diagrame